# joomla url is not working

Tags: php, joomla

I have transferred my project from one server to new server.

> index.php/component/mylist/?ctrl=list&action=catalog&Itemid=573&manufacturer=101291

This url is working only in old server but not in new server.

I used this url instead of above url for new server

> index.php?option=com_mylist&ctrl=list&action=catalog&Itemid=573&manufacturer=101291

Is working fine in new server

Can we work this url in new server

> index.php/component/mylist/?ctrl=list&action=catalog&Itemid=573&manufacturer=101291

Comment: Rather lost here. Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the .htaccess file from the old server within root of the installation. Also, make sure the Global Configuration settings are identical.

**Edit**

The easiest way to transfer a Joomla site to a new server is to use https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html

Just backup the site with the component then use the kickstart.php file to extract the website. You may need to rename/copy the .htaccess file still.

Answer (score 0):

Use apache? only apache server works an .htaccess file configuration. IIS and others not work these  method.

Your ftp client show the hidden files? .foo is hidden for linux servers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your old server, you had default sef enabled (configuration->enable sef).
On your new server, you have it disabled.